# Change between switch and check box if the API is changed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to change between check box and switch when API is less than 14 i want check box to appear when API is more than 14 i want switch to appear i  try a lot to import switch to API less than 14 but i can't if any one can help me to import switch to API less than 14 or help me to make layout for different API

Comment: Please, post your code what you have tried.

Comment: I try nothing for make 2 layout i don't know how to make 2 layout for different API version

Comment: You can place them in one layout and change their visibility according to the API level.

Comment: How ? I think it will give me error because the min API in android manifest is 9

Comment: Why don't you just create an if/else in your onCreate, if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK)) < 14)) setContentView(R.layout.pre_14_layout); else setContentView(R.layout.14_plus_layout); or something like that

Comment: That's what I'm saying about.

Comment: In more than 14 XML this error appears View requires API level 14 (current min is 9): <Switch>

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the situation programmatically by checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` as follows

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    // show Switch
} else {
    // show CheckBox
}
```

Or you can create different layout XML for different API level and put them into respective layout folder as below

```
res/layout/mylayout.xml       (API Level 8+)
res/layout-v11/mylayout.xml    (API Level 11+)
res/layout-v14/mylayout.xml   (API Level 14+)
```

Comment: this error appears IN XML View requires API level 14 (current min is 9): <Switch>

Comment: I don't understands the update can you discuss it please

Answer (score 0):

Use resource folders to use `CheckBox` as default and `Switch` for API level 14 or above.

`res/layout/compound_button.xml`:

```
<CheckBox
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`res/layout-v14/compound_button.xml`:

```
<Switch
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

You can then include `compound_button` in other layouts, say `activity_main.xml`:

```
<include
  android:id="@+id/turbo"
  layout="@layout/compound_button" />
```

Since both `CheckBox` and `Switch` extends `CompoundButton`, you can get its value like this in your Java code:

```
CompoundButton turbo = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.turbo);
if (!turbo.isChecked()) {
  // Slow down the computer
}
```

Watch my talk for more information (starting at 21:25):
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/android-fragmentation-myth

Comment: I don't understand this answer

Comment: shoud it not be `res/layout-v14/compound_button.xml`